# Gallery app crashes when trying to view photos or videos

Tags: gallery, sony-xperia-mini-pro

The Gallery app on my phone does not show any of my photos or videos. If I try to view them from the camera app the screen just goes black and exits to the home screen. I have an Xperia Mini Pro. Is there any way I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the **data** and **cache** of the gallery from App Manager of your phone's setting.